# Django 1.4 config settings

Tags: django, heroku, django-settings

I have been using Django a long time but I recently upgraded to 1.4.

When I created a new project, here is how it was made:

```
-my_proj
    -my_app
    -settings.py
    -urls.py
    -wsgi.py
-venv
-manage.py
-requirements.txt
```

I am working on my local machine as well as on Heroku.  The issue is how I am supposed to refer to modules.

When I am on my local machine, everything seems like it is supposed to be referred to as `my_proj.my_app`.  However, when I am on Heroku, everything has to be referred to as `my_app`.

Does anyone know of some areas that I should look that might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Moving your `my_app` dir to the root directory of your project (where `manage.py` is located), as it was done in [Django tutorial for Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) will make it a top level module and will allow you to import them just as `my_app` on your local machine. I would suggest trying this and checking whether Heroku behaves the same.

Alternatively, adding an empty `__init__.py`, if there there isn't one already, in your `my_proj` directory might also help Heroku see `my_proj` as a top-level module, thus allowing you to import your app as `my_proj.my_app`.

I hope my advice was insightful and helpful.

Good luck!